Powershell Binary Module - Could not load file or Assembly "NetMQ, Version=4.0.1.13"
I am trying to build a PowerShell binary module with the NetMQ Package (Version 4.0.1.13).
I only have created a server class with two parameters (Message and Address).
Steps to reproduce the exception:

Build class library (dotnet build)
Publish class library (dotnet publish)
Open PowerShell 5 console
Import the module (ZeroMq4Ps.dll)
Execute the Powershell cmdlet (Send-ZeroMQMessage)

Does anyone have inputs to fix my problem? Thank you!
ZeroMq4Ps.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>ZeroMq4Ps</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NetMQ" Version="4.0.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

SendZeroMQMessageCmdlet.cs
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Send, "ZeroMQMessage")]
public class SendZeroMQMessageCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        using (var publisher = new PublisherSocket())
        {
            publisher.Bind(Address);
            publisher.SendFrame(Message);
        }
    }
}

Output (Sorry the text is written in german):


Is the NetMQ assembly present n the directory bin/Debug/netstandard2.0?

No, the NetMQ assembly is only in the publish directory. I've copied the all dll libraries from the publish directory and now it works. Thanks for your help!

But why are these libraries not available in the debug directory by default?

Or the other way round: why don't you use the files in the publish directory?

That's my mistake. I misunderstood the Debug folder with their packages.
